# Phalcon Ajax Response Returns HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, phalcon, volt

So i am trying to implement this:
https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/wiki/Dependent-Select-Dropdown

And i have everything working, it creates the selects, populates the first select and when i choose a value it correctly returns values like below when i call grabStatesAction in the controller:

[{"id":"2","name":"Section1"},{"id":"24","name":"Section2"}"}]

However if i alert the response inside the javascript it does not return that at all and instead returns a bunch of HTML from the page.

Here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#id_product").change(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: '/admin/section/grabSection/',
                data: {"id": value},
                success: function(response){
                    $("#selectSection option")
                        .not(":first").remove();

                    alert(response);
                    parsed = $.parseJSON(response);


                    $.each(parsed, function(key, value) {
                        $("#selectSection")
                            .append($("<option></option>")
                            .attr("value",value.id)
                            .text(value.name));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

And here is the controller

```
public function grabSectionAction()
    {
        $id=2; //hardcoded for testing purposes
        $data = Sections::find(array(
            'columns' => array('id_section, section'),
            'conditions' => 'active = 1 AND id_section = :id:',
            'bind' => array('id'=>$id)
        ));
        $resData = array();
        foreach ($data as $result) {
            $resData[] = array("id"=>$result->id_section, "name"=>$result->section);
        }

        echo json_encode($resData);
    }
```

The page with the selects is a modal window with a form. I was thinking maybe the page should have application-type set as json and maybe that was the issue but if i do that then the form will break. I did set the application type in the javascript to json. Any ideas what i am doing wrong or is there any specific additional info you need just let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below.. Use `Console.log` instead of alert to see full response string.
MoreInfo: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api

```
public function grabSectionAction()
{
    $this->view->disable();

    //Create a response instance
    $response = new \Phalcon\Http\Response();

    $id = 2; //hardcoded for testing purposes
    $data = Sections::find(array(
        'columns' => array('id_section, section'),
        'conditions' => 'active = 1 AND id_section = :id:',
        'bind' => array('id' => $id)
    ));
    $resData = array();
    foreach ($data as $result) {
        $resData[] = array("id" => $result->id_section, "name" => $result->section);
    }

    //Set the content of the response
    $response->setContent(json_encode($resData));

    //Return the response
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, once i seen the disable view code line it hit me, thats why i was seeing the HTML as i hadnt disabled the view. I didnt even need to change anything else, all it needed was the view disabled and worked instantly